# Limit an app to work in a certain building?

Tags: ios, geolocation, location, cllocationmanager

Is there a way to get a location and get the building your're in like a college campus? So far, I can find the exact house that a user is in by finding their address from their location via placemarks, but I don't know how I would get the college they are in. Would I have to hard code the coordinates of different campuses or is there something within Apple's framework that can search for these special types of locations?

I want to limit my app's functionality to any/all college campuses, but I don't know how to use the location manager to do this specific task.

Here is the code I have to search up the exact location of a user and return an address:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
CLLocation *crnLoc = [locations lastObject];

[self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

// Reverse Geocoding
[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:crnLoc completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    // NSLog(@"Found placemarks: %@, error: %@", placemarks, error);
    if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
        placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
        locationLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@\n%@ %@\n%@\n%@",
                              placemark.subThoroughfare, placemark.thoroughfare,
                              placemark.postalCode, placemark.locality,
                              placemark.administrativeArea,
                              placemark.country];
    } else {

    }
} ];
}
```